# object with student class in java

Tags: java, syntax

Create a new project to add a class.  The class should have following instance:

```
field 1 // for input of student ID number  
field 2 // for input of student name  
field 3 // for input gander "M" or "F"  
field 4 // for input student major - network or security
```

The class should have no-arg constructor that will help you in creating object.  In order to test your class,create another class that contain the main method (i.e. your main program).  The code in the main method should create "n" number of objects,  where "n" depends on how many student you want to have.  The main method should allow an input for "n" number of student and print out the detail in a format having suitable title.

---

This my solution and I found errors. Try to help me, please.
This my 1st question.

```
import java.util.*;

public class StudentClass 
{   
  int studentdID;
  String studentName,studentMajor;
  char age;

  StudentClass(int s1,String n1,String b1,char a1) 
  {
    studentdID=s1;studentName=n1;studentMajor=b1;age=a1;
  }

  public void display() 
  {
    System.out.println(this.studentdID+" "+this.studentName+" "+this.studentMajor+" "+this.age+" ");
  }

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
 int s;
 String n,k,g;
 char ch;
 int num;

 Scanner ss=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("HOW MANY STUDENT");
 num=ss.nextInt();

 StudentClass[]a=new StudentClass[num];
 for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) 
 {
  System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT ID OF STUEDNT"+(i+1));
  s=ss.nextInt();
  System.out.println("ENTER GENDER OF STUDENT"+(i+1));
  g = ss.next();
  ch = g.charAt(0);

  System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT NAME OF STUDENT"+(i+1));
  n=ss.next();
  System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT MAJOR OF STUDENT"+(i+1));
  n=ss.next();

  a[i]=new StudentClass(s,n,k,g);
}
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) 
{
 a[i].display();         
}

}
```

}

Comment: Oooooooooopssssssssssssssssssssssss....

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere?

Comment: Don't post whole of your code, just post the part of it that makes some error

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You're not asking any question or reporting any problem. You need to be more specific. You also need to format your code in a readable way. Remeber that you're the one needing help, so make it as easy as possible for us to help you :) Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask questions.

Comment: it's necessary to post all code maybe anther errors will be found

Comment: @user2418623 We're not your teacher. You should pose a **specific** question. This is not a code review site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should think a bit more on how you name variables and read up on Java coding style conventions. Also read up on handling input and exceptions.

Anyhow, there are two obvious errors in the code:

When you call the constructor you pass the wrong variables as arguments:

```
a[i]=new StudentClass(s,n,k,g);
```

Probably should be

```
a[i]=new StudentClass(s,n,k,ch);
```

And you are never assigning to variable k, instead you assign to n twice:

```
System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT NAME OF STUDENT"+(i+1));
n=ss.next();
System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT MAJOR OF STUDENT"+(i+1));
n=ss.next();
```

Should be:

```
System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT NAME OF STUDENT"+(i+1));
n=ss.next();
System.out.println("ENTER STUDENT MAJOR OF STUDENT"+(i+1));
k=ss.next();
```

Finally, consider picking up a nice Java book and work through the tutorials that Oracle provide.